# Fetch raw data from google analytics without GA4 and UA

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am facing issues using Google Analytics APIs (GA4 & UA). First, UA provided historical data till 07-2023 and GA provided data from 06-2023. So I can't use one of them alone. This leads to inaccurate data because some matrix definition is different between both data models(for example number of users and session). So I'm wondering if there is a way to extract raw data without a Google Analytics premium account.

Comment: Ga4 and UA are completely different systems there will always be inaccurate data if you try to compare them or the data they produce

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I know there are differences, but if I represent a dashboard for our data from the beginning of 2023 till now it will not be accurate. That's why I was thinking of extracting raw data. please let me know if you have a solution for my case.

Comment: You can't extract raw data from ga.   Unless you configured a export to big Query